# How to get the "oauth access secret" for a connection to the soundcloud api

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-ruby, soundcloud

I am new to using APIs of Websites. But since a long time I wanted to learn this and today started with the simple example of how to access information from soundcloud. Here is the code of the simple example from their [website](https://github.com/soundcloud/ruby-api-wrapper/wiki/Getting-started)

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'soundcloud-ruby-api-wrapper'
require 'soundcloud'

gem 'oauth'
require 'oauth'


# Create a Soundcloud OAuth consumer token object
sc_consumer = Soundcloud.consumer('YOUR_APPLICATION_CONSUMER_TOKEN','YOUR_APPLICATION_CONSUMER_SECRET')

# Create an OAuth access token object
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(sc_consumer, 'YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET')

# Create an authenticated Soundcloud client, based on the access token
sc_client = Soundcloud.register({:access_token => access_token})

# Get the logged in user 
my_user = sc_client.User.find_me

# Display his full name
p "Hello, my name is #{my_user.full_name}"
```

I know what to set as:

- 'YOUR_APPLICATION_CONSUMER_TOKEN'
- 'YOUR_APPLICATION_CONSUMER_SECRET'

as this was given when registering a application on soundcloud.

I set the 'YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN' to http://api.soundcloud.com/oauth/access_token
which was also written on the soundcloud site, but I have no idea where to get the

**_YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET_** from.

Is this access secret also a random string that I get from somewhere, do I have to generate it by myself.

---

**EDIT** As suggested in the answer of the Elite Gentlemen I also tried the Soundcloud example on authentication. I post here the piece of code which already leads to the error:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'soundcloud-ruby-api-wrapper'
require 'soundcloud'

# oAuth setup code:  
# Enter your consumer key and consumer secret values here:
@consumer_application = {:key => 'QrhxUWqgIswl8a9ESYw', :secret => 'tqsUGUD3PscK17G2KCQ4lRzilA2K5L5q2BFjArJzmjc'}

# Enter the path to your audio file here.  
path_to_audio_file = "your/absolute/path/to/audio_file.ext"

# Set up an oAuth consumer.  
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new @consumer_application[:key], @consumer_application[:secret], 
{
  :site               => 'http://api.sandbox-soundcloud.com', 
  :request_token_path => '/oauth/request_token',
  :access_token_path  => '/oauth/access_token',
  :authorize_path     => '/oauth/authorize'
}

# Obtain an oAuth request token
puts "Get request token"
request_token = @consumer.get_request_token
```

The error message I receive then is:

> OAuth::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
>
> method token_request  in consumer.rb at
>   line 217 method get_request_token in
>   consumer.rb at line 139 at top
>   level in test1.rb at line 25

How can this simple example fail?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is very simple. My problem was that I had
registered my application on the soundcloud production system 
soundcloud.com but directed my requests against sandbox-soundcloud.com.

I had to go to sandbox-soundcloud.com, register a new user account and make a 
new client application and everything worked perfectly.

More information on the Sandbox is available here: 
http://github.com/soundcloud/api/wiki/Appendix-B-Sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure if this info is up to date, but it has started to explain some mysteries to me.

Answer (score 1):

As with OAuth, you will have to register your application with Soundcloud if you want the end-user to access Soundcloud's *protected* resources through your application.

When you request an `access_token` from Soundcloud using OAuth, it will return you and `access_token` and a `oauth_token_secret`. That `oauth_token_secret` is what you mentioned as ***YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET***

I don't know how familiar you are with OAuth. The documentation can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).

---

**Edit** OAuth authorization scheme changed a while back, (e.g. getting an access token requires you to specify a `oauth_verifier`).

See the [SoundCloud example on Authentication](https://github.com/soundcloud/api/wiki/02-authentication) using the latest OAuth specification.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I think you did not understand what my problem is, maybe because it is too simple. For requesting the access_token  (access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(sc_consumer, 'YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET')) I already have to know the **YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET** You know what I mean?

Comment: @dedan, for your question, the answer is yes, but that seems to be like an old OAuth authentication scheme. View my edited post for more.

Comment: ok, I'll try this new example that you posted in your edit tomorrow. I just wondered, because the one I used was last edited on September 13, 2010. Thanks a lot, I'll post my results here tomorrow

Comment: I also tried what you suggested (see edit of my post) but it still does not work. I suspect it might also be a problem with soundclous!? I'll try to ask in their user group